# Tipo varchar limite mysql

Tags: mysql

Alguém consegue explicar qual o limite do tipo varchar? Li o seguinte:

**um banco de dados MySQL tem um limite de 65.535 bytes (para a linha inteira)**

**Porém, como a contagem de bytes é realizada?**

Meu pensamento inicial é de que a contagem é realizada somando-se a outros campos de tipo varchar.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Rohan, a conta considera todas as colunas, com exceção das colunas dos tipos blob e text. Veja detalhes na documentação do MySQL: [Limits on Table Column Count and Row Size](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/column-count-limit.html).

Comment: Olá, obrigado pela resposta, sanou a minha dúvida!

Comment: Por nada. Estamos todos aqui para ajudar e aprender. ;-)